# How to copy bytes from buffer into the managed struct?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a problem with getting the code to work **in a managed** environment (VS2008 C++/CLI Win Forms App). The problem is I **cannot declare the unmanaged struct** (is that even possible?) inside the managed code, so I've declared a managed struct but now I have a problem **how to copy bytes from buffer into that struct**. Here is the pure C++ code that obviously works as expected:

```
typedef struct GPS_point {
  float point_unknown_1;
  float latitude;
  float longitude;
  float altitude;            // x10000
  float time;
  int point_unknown_2;
  int speed;                 // x100
  int manually_logged_point; // flag (1 --> point logged manually)
  } track_point;

int offset           = 0;
int filesize         = 256;  // simulates filesize
int point_num        = 10;   // simulates number of records

int main () {

char *buffer_dyn = new char[filesize];  // allocate RAM
// here, the file would have been read into the buffer
buffer_dyn[0xa8] = 0x1e;  // simulates the speed data (1e 00 00 00)
buffer_dyn[0xa9] = 0x00;
buffer_dyn[0xaa] = 0x00;
buffer_dyn[0xab] = 0x00;

offset = 0x90;  // if the data with this offset is transfered trom buffer
                // to struct, int speed is alligned with the buffer at the
                // offset of 0xa8

track_point *points = new track_point[point_num];
points[0].speed    = 0xff;  // (debug) it should change into 0x1e
memcpy(&points[0],buffer_dyn+offset,32);

cout << "offset: " << offset << "\r\n";
//cout << "speed: " << points[0].speed << "\r\n";
printf ("speed : 0x%x\r\n",points[0].speed);
printf("byte at offset 0xa8: 0x%x\r\n",(unsigned char)buffer_dyn[0xa8]);  // should be 0x1e

delete[] buffer_dyn;  // release RAM
delete[] points;

/*
What I need is to rewrite the lines 29 and 31 to work in the managed code (VS2008 Win Forms C++/CLI)
What should I have after:

array<track_point^>^ points = gcnew array<track_point^>(point_num);

so I can copy 32 bytes from buffer_dyn to the managed struct declared as

typedef ref struct GPS_point {
  float point_unknown_1;
  float latitude;
  float longitude;
  float altitude;             // x10000
  float time;
  int point_unknown_2;
  int speed;                  // x100
  int manually_logged_point;  // flag (1 --> point logged manually)
  } track_point;
*/

return 0;
}
```

Here is the [paste to codepad.org](http://codepad.org/G2Hlg65S) so it can be seen the code is OK.

**What I need is to rewrite these two lines:**

```
track_point *points = new track_point[point_num];
memcpy(&points[0],buffer_dyn+offset,32);
```

to something that will work in a managed application. I wrote:

```
array<track_point^>^ points = gcnew array<track_point^>(point_num);
```

and am now trying to reproduce the described copying of the data from buffer over the struct, but haven't any idea how it should be done.

Alternatively, **if there is a way to use an unmanaged struct** in the same way shown in my code, then I would like to avoid working with managed struct.

Comment: Why are you having trouble declaring the unmanaged struct in managed code? I can help you there, if it is an option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, not only it is an option - it is a preferable one!! :-) Well, if I try to declare a 'normal' struct in a button click event function I am getting 'error C3923: local class, struct or union definitions are not allowed in a member function of a managed class'. And if I try to declare it inside namespace (where one would have declared global variables), I am getting: 'error C2814: a native type cannot be nested within a managed type'. So, I didn't know where to declare the unmanaged struct and had to put 'ref' to declare the managed one :-/

Comment: investigate #managed and #unmanaged

Comment: Thank you **very much**!! After reading [the article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0adb9zxe.aspx) as you suggested, I've put the function inside `#pragma managed (push,off)` and `#pragma managed (pop)`, declared unmanaged struct, passed the pointer to the buffer as parameter to the function, and everything works as expected!! :-) Thank you again for your help (it was exactly the solution to my problem) and have a nice day! I think you should write something as an answer so I could mark your article as accepted.